# sort child / parent in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, coalesce

I have a MySQL table which is as follows:

```
member_id | name        | parent     |....
   1      | john        | 0          |
   2      | alex        | 0          |
   3      | nikita      | 1          |
   4      | sarah       | 1          |
   .
   .
   .
```

i want to sort with `parrent`.
i try this but not work:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY COALESCE(`parrent`,`member_id`),`parrent` !=0,`member_id`
```

all child sorted, but parent not with them.

i want this result :

```
member_id | name        | parent     |....
   2      | alex        | 0          |
   1      | john        | 0          |
   3      | nikita      | 1          |
   4      | sarah       | 1          |
   .
   .
   .
```

parents first and then childs.

is there a better solution to implement this table?
I need a table that contain families

Comment: you have 2 different references. Is it meant to be `parent` or `parrent`?

Comment: could you show which result you want  to have,

Comment: I see no null values in your sample data, how come coalesce()?

Comment: I explained in the post what results I wanted. I generally need a table that includes families

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coalesce()` doesn't work because the parent is `0`.  You can use `nullif()` instead:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(parent, 0), member_id),
        (parent = 0) DESC,
        member_id
```

Notice that I use `(parent = 0) DESC` for the second key.  I prefer the logic to express the *matches* we want first, with `DESC` to put true values before false ones.

Comment: @FarzadKamali . . . I see that.  `GREATEST()` does not work in all cases.  You need `NULLIF()` or a `CASE` expression.